# Bash command to retrieve latest Mailinator email? curl?

Tags: bash, email, curl

I want to retrieve the last email I got in mailinator, in a bash script. I was hoping that curl can do that.
I tried

```
curl --url "http://mailinator.com/showmail.jsp?email=username&msgnum=1"
```

and

```
curl http://mailinator.com/inbox.jsp?to=username
```

and also the first command with inbox.jsp instead of showmail.jsp, but to no avail.

Comment: Always quote the URL since it might contain characters that are special to the shell.

Comment: mailinator uses javascript to load the emails, I don't believe `curl` will be able to do this for you. edit - it can, but only if you sign up and get an API token - http://mailinator.com/apidocs.jsp